# Why is ls show file size different when changing block-size?

Tags: files, ls

I wanted to check my filesystem backup size

```
ls -lia backup.tgz 
17 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 84972633333 мај 28 10:05 backup.tgz
```

With block-size M

```
 ls -l --block-size=M backup.tgz 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 81037M мај 28 10:05 backup.tgz
```

Finally with block-size G

```
ls -l --block-size=G backup.tgz 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 80G мај 28 10:05 backup.tgz
```

Could someone explain such a huge difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The values are shown using powers of 2, not powers of 10; so 1M is 1,048,576 bytes, and 1G is 1,073,741,824 bytes.

If you divide accordingly, the values match the `ls` output (rounded up):

```
$ echo $((84972633333.0/1024/1024))
81036.218007087708

$ echo $((84972633333.0/1024/1024/1024))
79.136931647546589
```

You can specify `KB`, `MB`, `GB` etc. instead to use powers of 10:

```
ls -l --block-size=MB backup.tgz
```

See [the section on block sizes](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Block-size.html#Block-size) in the `coreutils` documentation for details.

Comment: and there are also rounding (errors) involved. Usually it rounds down instead of up, and it can be quite disconcerting to see 0GB in an output.

Comment: @Rui do you still have examples of file sizes being rounded down? On my systems, even a 1-byte file shows up as 1G. The docs say “Fractional block counts are rounded up to the nearest integer.” and that matches my experience.

Comment: There are two different implementations of df afair. I had problems both with rounding down and having two different df implementations on a wrapper script for automating netbackup installation/upgrade operations recently. Had to use MB instead of GB to get around that.

Comment: Ah, right, `df`; I was thinking about `ls` (as per the question). `df` also rounds up which is unfortunate since it overestimates the available space... (For a script though I’d use byte sizes.)